# show the names which usage is morethan 80%

Tags: scripting

I have a file like below having 'N' number of lines.
I want to display the heading and diskinfo which are more than 80% usage.

```
Server1
===========
TestDisk,76% 
disk1,22% 
disk2,22%
Server2 
===========
disk1,49%
Test,39%
disk40,82%
```

Can somebody help me !!

Comment: You can parse the disk usage using `while read` and `usage=`echo $LINE | grep -v Server | grep -v === | cut -d , -f 2 | tr -d \% `; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below worked for me, Thank you j658063.mvrht.com for your help.

```
cat filename | while read i
do
    if [ -z $(echo $i | grep "%") ] 
    then
        echo $i

    else
        if (( $(echo "$(echo $i | awk -F "," '{print $2}'| awk -F "%" '{print $1}' ) > 80" | bc -l)  ))
        then
          echo $i

        fi
     fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If `<filename>` is the output, a dirty script would be

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <filename> | while read i
do

    if [ -z $(echo $i | grep "%") ] 
    then
        echo $i                
    else
        if (( $(echo "$(echo $i | grep -o '[0-9,]*%' | sed 's/,/./;s/%//' ) > 80" | bc -l)  ))
        then
          echo $i   
        fi
     fi
done
```

Comment: I just get a file. No idea how it got generated. I tried replacing cmd with cat <filename>.. didnt helped

Comment: I am getting the entire file as output. logic is missing somewhere !!!

Comment: Using my precise script with your filename instead of <filename> I get [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23954340/) output

Comment: I think, The output should contain disk40 as it is morethan 80% usage

Comment: here is the problem, echo $i | grep -o '[0-9,]*%' | sed 's/,/./;s/%//'  is not properly giving the exact '%' number, it is containing . and other numbers in the first column.

Comment: I replace sed with awk.. helped me....